# function wp_insert_post() inside single-{customposttype}.php clearing custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

i have single-mypost.php to display mypost single post, in which user can submit a form for msgs (msgs is another custom post type for private messages). when user submits form new post is perfectly added to msgs but single mypost customfields are changing to empty. i have added code am using

```
<form method="post" action="" class="gform" onSubmit="return validatebid()">
    <h2>Message</h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="msgfor" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="msgby" value="<?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="msgdate" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>"/>
    <div class="row">
        <label>Message</label>
        <div class="field">
            <textarea name="textareafield"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="msg" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="red-btn" value="Message Now"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

once user submits form am using wp_insert_post to insert post. code i have added before get_header.

```
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'task' ] ) && $_POST[ 'task' ] == 'msg' ) {
$post_info = array(
    'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST[ "msgfor" ] . '-' . 
     $_POST[ "msgby" ] . '-' . $_POST[ "msgdate" ] ),
    'post_content' => $_POST[ 'textareafield' ],
    'post_type' => 'msgs',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$pid = wp_insert_post( $post_info );
echo $pid;
update_post_meta( $pid, "msgfor", $_POST[ "msgfor" ] );
update_post_meta( $pid, "msgby", $_POST[ "msgby" ] );
update_post_meta( $pid, "msgdate", $_POST[ "msgdate" ] );
}
```

Comment: Include all the required code especially the action you are using for the insert post.

Comment: thanks for reply bro, this the form with fields and once user submits am using "wp_insert_post". this the function code i have added.

Answer (score 0):

Please add

```
<?php if ( isset( $_POST[ 'textareafield' ] ) ) {            
echo $_POST[ 'textareafield' ];
}?>
```

between `<textarea name="textareafield"></textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

I think the second part of the code should be in a separate file, it will look something like this:

```
require('wp-load.php'); // make sure that it is the correct path to this file

... your code here ...
```

As an option, make the form submission via AJAX, with `wp_ajax_` action hook.

The key idea is not using `wp_insert_post()` inside your `single-mypost.php` template.